# Using NOT CONTAINS to compare results between 2 temporary tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

So this one's got me scratching my head: I can't get the NOT CONTAINS in my third query below to work right (where I'm trying to compare a result set in one temporary table against another).

Context of this situation is website pages being tracked for clients by visitor tracking software.

The goal of the below is to fill the #Domains temp table with all website domains attached to a set of clients, fill the #Pages temp table with all pages we've tracked visits to and then compare the results to see if we're tracking visits to pages that aren't registered as client domains. Basically I want to return EVERYTHING from #Pages that isn't like either #Domains.Domain1, #Domains.Domain2 or #Domains.Domain3 for each ClientID (the unique identifier for each client).

```
SELECT  Name, Domain1, Domain2, Domain3, ClientID, RecordID
        INTO    #Domains
        FROM    Domains
        WHERE   RecordID IN (Subquery that I wont paste here)

SELECT  ClientID, PageLocation
        INTO #Pages
        FROM PageLocations
        WHERE ClientID IN ( SELECT  ClientID 
                            FROM    #Domains)

SELECT  *
        FROM    #Pages
        WHERE   NOT CONTAINS (#Pages.PageLocation, #Domains.Domain1, #Domains.Domain2, #Domains.Domain3) AND
        #Pages.ClientID = #Domains.ClientID
```

So my two tables currently look like this (not including RecordID as it's only relevant to the subquery):

```
#Domains
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Name        ClientID        Domain1           Domain2          Domain3         |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Example     11111           www.example.com   NULL             NULL            |
| Test        22222           www.test.com      www.new.com      NULL            |
| Website     33333           www.website.co.uk NULL                             |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

    #Pages
+----------+--+-----------------------+
| ClientID |  |     PageLocation      |
+----------+--+-----------------------+
|    11111 |  | www.example.com       |
|    11111 |  | www.example.com/about |
|    11111 |  | www.example.com/help  |
|    22222 |  | www.test.com          |
|    22222 |  | www.test.com/help     |
|    22222 |  | www.new.com           |
|    22222 |  | www.fake.com          |
|    33333 |  | www.ultra.co.uk       |
|    33333 |  | www.ultra.co.uk/news  |
|    33333 |  | www.website.co.uk     |
+----------+--+-----------------------+
```

And what I'd hope to return would be:

```
+----------+--+-----------------+
| ClientID |  |  PageLocation   |
+----------+--+-----------------+
|    22222 |  | www.fake.com    |
|    33333 |  | www.ultra.co.uk |
+----------+--+-----------------+
```

Sorry that's so wordy, but basically I'm getting a syntax error with my NOT CONTAINS in the final query so I don't think I'm using it correctly, and I'm not even certain that NOT CONTAINS is absolutely the right choice here, so any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `contains` performs  full-text search on full-text indexed columns. I'm not sure that temporary tables are full-text indexed.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try by using `NOT IN` instead of `NOT CONTAINS` and you have to join your two tables.

Comment: Nope, haven't tried that yet. I went straight to 'NOT CONTAINS' because I wasn't sure about the syntax for NOT IN multiple columns in a temp table. I'm not actually sure of the difference between them either actually!

Comment: wait you don't want to see the columns. then why don't you write specific columns you want to see instead of *

Comment: @Konrad Just replace `NOT CONTAINS` with `NOT IN`

Comment: @Konrad Also why is 11111 not being returned? Why do you only want to see 22222 and 33333

Comment: If I change the final SELECT to NOT IN I get an error I've never seen before which I've transcribed below:


'Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.'


EDIT: And 11111 would not be returned because www.example.com is in #Domains and is therefore a valid domain to be tracking.

Comment: Do you want ClidneId and PageLocation where PageLocation is not exist in Domain1, Domain2 and Domain3 if so then I am going to post the query ??

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  
     *
FROM 
     #Pages
          join #Domains on  #Pages.ClientID = #Domains.ClientID
WHERE
     #Pages.PageLocation not like #Domains.Domain1 + '%'
     and #Pages.PageLocation not like #Domains.Domain2 + '%'
     and #Pages.PageLocation not like #Domains.Domain3 + '%'
```

Comment: this query wont run, `#Domains` not part of `from`

Comment: @Aツ Forgot the Join

Comment: But if I join to #Domains on ClientID rather than making it part of the WHERE clause, that seems like it might do it. Going to test it now.

EDIT: Nope, still getting this collation conflict which is a new error to me.